# can't replace file in amazon s3 bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

can't replace file in amazon s3 bucket

when i am going to upload an image to `amazon s3` bucket it shows error like below
`An item with the same key has already been added`.

i have uploaded an image file and i wanted replace that image when i need it. but it does not allow.

how can I fix it?

i am using C#

```
 using (s3Client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client("key",   "secret key", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
            {
                var stream2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Save(stream2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                stream2.Position = 0;
                PutObjectRequest request2 = new PutObjectRequest();
                request2.InputStream = stream2;
                request2.BucketName = "ezcimassets";
                request2.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                fileName = webpage + ".jpeg";
                //fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + webpage + ".jpeg";)
                request2.Key = "WebThumbnails/" + fileName;

                Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(request2);

            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the actual response from amazon s3 ? Amazon does not prevent to update the existing object. It does overwrite on put object request api.
Also first confirm that your code is executing the above code section, I think before executing the code mentioned above of putobject, your app is checking for existing by GET or HEAD object request api.

Comment: I could find the solution , this row must be edited as   request2.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line must be changed  as

request2.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite

Comment: what if I want only the authenticated users to read the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an object with that key already exists, and if so delete it:

```
public bool Exists(string fileKey, string bucketName)
{
        try
        {
            response = _s3Client.GetObjectMetadata(new GetObjectMetadataRequest()
               .WithBucketName(bucketName)
               .WithKey(key));

            return true;
        }

        catch (Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                return false;

            //status wasn't not found, so throw the exception
            throw;
        }
}

public void Delete(string fileKey, string bucketName)
{
    DeleteObjectRequest request = new DeleteObjectRequest();
    request.BucketName = bucketName;
    request.Key        = fileKey;
    client.DeleteObject(request);
}
```